# dynamically allocated string array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, memory-management, dynamic

When I attempt to run this code it crashes.  There are no error messages.  When the program compiles and runs, it just displays the windows 7 message, "this program has stopped working.":

```
void readGameFile(string ** entries, int * num_entries, string ** story, int * num_lines)
{
    ifstream madlib("madlibs1.txt");
    string line;
    getline(madlib, line);
    *num_entries=stoi(line);
    *entries=new string [*num_entries];
    for (int i=0; i<*num_entries; i++)
    {
        getline(madlib,*entries[i]);
    }
```

I did a few tests, and it seems to assign `entries[0]` a value, and then crashes when attempting to assign `entries[1]` a value.  I am forced to use this function name, with those function parameters and parameter types specifically.  I also may not use malloc, vector or other answers I've seen.

Comment: Can you check using [`is_open()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/is_open) if the file has been opened ?

Comment: I have checked in various ways that the file opens.  It is capable of reading things from the file.  It seems to have to do with the way I am dynamically allocating.  Now it's giving me a debug error and says "abort has been called."

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<*num_entries; i++)` `num_entries` is a pointer. I guess you intended `*num_entries` in the loop condition

Comment: Yes sorry.  That's a typo. I fixed that

Comment: You would likely be surprised how much cleaner this is using `std::vector<std::string>` objects. That aside, exactly *none* of your io operations are being checked for success.

Comment: This is a dev's world...but it wouldn't be nothing, witouth a try or a catch (both)...

Comment: @Ameoo agreed. there are several things that could toss exceptions in this, `std::stoi` being one of them. And without a try-catch block handler, the program is as good as dead shortly thereafter.

Comment: @WhozCraig The try-catch block is the responsibility of the calling code.

Comment: @JamesKanze I'm sensing it unlikely there is one *at all*. (and I probably didn't communicate that very well, so apologies in hind-sight for that). I didn't mean this is where it should go. I meant *without* one *anywhere* that would explain the rather abrupt end-of-life this seems to be showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is one of precedence: you almost certainly
want:

```
getline( madlib, (*entries)[i]) );
```

Otherwise, you're indexing from the `string**`, then
dereferencing: `*(entries[i])`.

You also want to check the results of `getline`, possibly in the
loop:

```
for ( int i = 0; madlib && i != *num_entries; ++ i )...
```

as well as before the `std::stoi`.

And finally: I don't know why you are forced to use this
function signature.  It is horrible C++, and you should never
write anything like this.  Logically, `std::vector<string>`
would be a better solution, but even without it: your function
has 4 out parameters.  This would be better handled by returning
a `struct`.  And failing that, out parameters in C++ are
*usually* implemented by non-const reference, not by a pointer.
While there are arguments for using the pointer in some cases,
when it results in a pointer to a pointer, it's evil.  If
nothing else:

```
bool        //  Because we have to indicate whether it succeed or failed
readGameFile( std::string* &entries, int &num_entries, std::string* &story, int &num_lines )
//  ...
```

(This actually looks more like it should be constructor,
however, of a class with two data elements, `entries` and
`story`.)

Comment: +1 I was noticing the dereference precedence as well, but for the life of me couldn't come up with a presentation that made sense in my mind. I really like yours with the two examples.

Comment: It's all fixed now.  I appreciate it.  Thank you very much.  To answer your question, this is part of a college assignment.  Thus the silly restrictions...

Comment: @user2889285 If this is an assignment, I have my doubts about the competence of the person who gave it.